# registration form values are not getting inserted into database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Registration form values are not getting inserted into database in php. It is showing an error while using mysql_connect and when i am using mysqli_connect, the values are not getting inserted into database.

**Form.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
username <input type="text" name="username">
password <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="ok" name="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form") or die("not connected");

if(ISSET($_POST['SUBMIT'])){

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

mysql_query("insert into formval('username','password') values('$username','$password')");

}
?>
```

Comment: Because you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: You mixed `mysqli` and `mysql` and you don't have to put `'` around your columns. Also how about a end form tag ?

Comment: Just sticking an "i" on the end of your "now not working due to depreciated" `mysql_` functions is not ideal. Use parametrised statements as well (if this is the case, ignore me if not..)

Comment: Rizier123  -  I have modified the code, i have removed ' still values are not getting inserted. <?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form") or die("not connected");
if(ISSET($_POST['SUBMIT'])){

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

mysqli_query("insert into formval(username,password) values($username,$password)");
}
?>

Comment: You need to make use of mysql error reporting, so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form") or die("not connected");

 if($_POST['username']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){

  $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
  $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);

   mysqli_query($connection,"insert into formval(username,password)  values('$username','$password')");

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`.`mysql_` is deprecated. You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.Try this -

```
<?php
$connection=new mysqli("localhost","root","","form") or die("not connected");

if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])){

   $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
   $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

   mysqli_query($connection, "insert into formval(username,password) values('$username','$password')");

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the reason for -1?

Comment: What is the reason for copy/pasting the OP's non-working code with "try this"? (no explanation, query is still wrong)

Comment: When the answer has been added i think that was ok.. After that the code has been modified.I think you have noticed that also..

Comment: Yeah, I see you stuck a few more "i's" around the place. Perhaps explaining to the OP what you did to fix it would be useful, however. Plus some info on prepared statements, and using mysql error, would also be nice :) I've removed my downvote, now the answer at least uses mysqli.

Comment: actually the explanation are there in the comments thats why only added the procedure.

Comment: The issue I had and hence my downvote was because you still had the OP's `mysql_` function and not `mysqli_`. You might get some upvotes if you add at least brief summary as to what you have done, why, and perhaps mention they should use prepared statements. Up to you, of course ;)

Comment: sgt - The code you sent is also not working. I cant understand what is the problem whether the problem is in code or database.